# Is there an english translation of Ibn al Jawzi's Minhaj al qaṣidin

Tags: adab, books, translation

Is there an English translation of Ibn al-Jawzi's *Minhaj al-Qaṣidin*?
 I know of ibn Qudamah's *mukhtasar* of the book but I'm looking for a translation of the original.

Answer (score 2):

There is no English translation of Minhaj al-Qasidin wa Mufid al-Sadiqin (Arabic: منهاج القاصدين ومفيد الصادقين) as the Arabic version is not available in the first place. This book was lost long time ago, but I have heard that, for the first time, a Syrian publisher has distributed the book in Arabic, based on an old version found in Turkey. I have not seen this version. The manuscript in Arabic can be found [here](http://www.al-mostafa.info/data/arabic/depot/gap.php?file=m013834.pdf).

In the introduction of Ibn Qudamah's book of *Mukhtasar Minhaj al-Qasidin*, he mentioned that the book was an abridged version of *Minhaj al-Qasidin* by Ibn al-Qayyim, which is in itself an abridged version of *Ihya' 'Ulum al-Deen* by al-Ghazali.